# firebase - send weekly newsletters to registered users

Tags: android, email, firebase, firebase-authentication, newsletter

I have an android app with facebook login integrated with firebase authentication, users are getting registered with successfully.

What I want now is, I wanna send my registered users a weekly newsletter to the registered emails in firebase.

Is there any to achieve this...?

Comment: Save maild id on success of authentication using firebase real time database and when you want send mails ,retrive the data(maild id's) from firebase database then send letters to that maild id's...

Comment: The only problem with that is, I dont get email for every registering user, only some of them get through, one approach would be to opt for google sign but sticking to facebook login is required for my app

Comment: means if the user give wrong mail id ,in this case you can not reach him ,so when user give the mail id send conformation mail  to that mail id then only offer him to service or remind him that he may not get letters..

Answer (score 0):

Create a firebase function to send mail
and call that function in firebase schedule function

[Firebase Schedule functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) to run a function or do http call at scheduled time